# hook_civicrm_permission in a drupal module

Tags: api, permissions, developer, hooks

How should custom permissions created by hook_civicrm_permission be properly  checked?

Have defined custom permission like this:

```
function mymodulename_civicrm_permission(&$permissions) {
    $prefix = ts('SpecialPermissions') . ': '; // name of extension or module
    $permissions['SpecialPermissions'] = $prefix . ts('SpecialPermissions');
}
```

and checking it later on, same module, hook_civicrm_buildForm,  have tried every option listed below:

```
* if (CRM_Core_Permission::check('SpecialPermissions')) {
* if (CRM_Core_Permission::check('Drupal: SpecialPermissions')) {
* if (CRM_Core_Permission::check('CiviCRM: SpecialPermissions')) {
* if (CRM_Core_Permission::check('cms: SpecialPermissions')) {
```

Code looks like exactly according to specs from:
 * http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_permission
 * http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Permission+Reference

However, both test user with a corresponded permission AND Drupal user 1 (UID=1) are being affected, even when Drupal User 1 doesn't have role with custom permissions attached. Not sure if it is by design or something wrong with my implementation of this? Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be misreading this, but it sounds like you're saying that you've got a new permission, and the user with the role that has the permission granted is working just fine.  However, you're saying that Drupal user ID 1 is being treated as if it has the permission, even though it doesn't have any role with that permission.

If so, this is totally normal.  Drupal user ID 1 gets all permissions, even when using `CRM_Core_Permission::check('SpecialPermissions')`.  You should be able to confirm by creating another user without that permission and seeing that `CRM_Core_Permission::check('SpecialPermissions')` returns false.

Comment: Good to know, thanks; a bit unusual behaviour from a drupal user 1 point of view though.